# Export company name to .csv

Tags: powershell

Trying to export only the company name to a .csv file however it exports the length of the company name instead of the company name in text... This is the code in powershell, i'm surley missing something but I don't know what. Thanks for helping.

```
Connect-MsolService
$customers = Get-MsolPartnerContract -All
Write-Host "Found $($customers.Count) customers for $((Get-MsolCompanyInformation).displayname)."
$CSVpath = "C:\Temp\UserLicenseReport.csv"
  
foreach ($customer in $customers) {
    Write-Host "$($customer.name)"
    $($customer.name) | Export-CSV -Path $CSVpath -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: What would you like the column header to be? "CompanyName"?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I only want all customers names.

Comment: If you just want a flat list of names then you don't want a CSV. Use `Set-Content` instead, it'll append each value to a new line

Comment: `(Get-MsolPartnerContract -All).Name | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Customers.txt'`. Append switch `-PassThru` to also have that list of customer names on screen

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

```
Connect-MsolService
$customers = Get-MsolPartnerContract -All

Set-Content -Path "C:\Temp\UserLicenseReport.csv" -Value $customers.name
```